# FormUrlEncodedContent parameters on httpclient post

Tags: c#, post, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have to post into a html form listed below.

```
<input type="text" name="user[username]" value="">
<input type="password" name="user[password]" >
```

With rest sharp it works without any problem - code bellow :

```
var clientRest = new RestClient(url);
var restRequest = new RestRequest();

restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
restRequest.AddParameter("user[username]", username);
restRequest.AddParameter("user[password]", password);
restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

IRestResponse responseRestSharp = clientRest.Execute(restRequest);
string content = responseRestSharp.Content;
```

But when i try that self with the HttpClient provided by System.Net.Http i dont get loged in into the session on the response - code bellow :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
  {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[username]", username),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[password]", password)

    string response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    ....
```

Im asking myself if the `FormUlrEncodedContent` transforms correctly it into a `name="user[username]"`  and `name="user[password]"` like restsharp does it with its AddParameter.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing await. Did you follow an example from online?

```
string response = await client.PostAsync
```

Comment: im calling Result thats why i dont need a await and it sync

Comment: All the examples I see use await with a variable and then use the variable. Worth a try.